# Estouro Aritmético C++

Tags: c++

Olá, sou iniciante na linguagem C++, fazendo alguns exercícios me deparei com uma mensagem que não interferiu em nada minha conta, porém gostaria de saber exatamente o que ela significa e o que teria que fazer para deixar esse calculo 100% certo para o c++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    float r, a;

    cout << "Digite o raio de um circulo: ";
        cin >> r;

        a=3.14 * (r * r);//Erro de estouro nessa linha

        cout << "\nA área de um circulo com " << r << " de raio é igual a " << a <<"\n\n";


    return 0;
}
```

C26451: Estouro aritmético usando o operador '*' em um valor de byte 4 e, em seguida, convertendo o resultado em um valor de byte 8. Converta o valor no tipo mais amplo antes de chamar o operador '*' para evitar estouro (io.2).

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: A constante `3.14` é considerada como do tipo `double` e você declarou `float r, a;`. Para trabalhar apenas como `float` utilize `a = 3.14f * (r * r);`. (um f ao final da constante de ponto flutuante indica que ela é do tipo float).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O tipo `double` tem mais precisão que o tipo `float`.

Você pode alterar o tipo das variáves `r` e `a` pra `double` ou mudar o literal para `3.14f` para que seja interpretado como `float`. Se não colocar o sufixo `f` o valor vai ser interpretado como `double`.

Comment: Muito interessante, após algumas pesquisas consegui entender a diferença de float para double, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

O aviso [C26451](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/code-quality/c26451?view=msvc-160) é disparado para indicar que o operador atual é usado em tipos que comportam uma quantidade maior de informações, ou seja, existe a chance de perda de dados (precisão dos números resultados da expressão). Para isso, você pode tentar converter o tipo da variável durante a operação como nos exemplos do link que deixei de referência.

Comment: Ajudou bastante, muito obrigado!